# mySQL select row only if count() as col1 <> col2

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I'm using the following SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT Col1, count(*) as Col2, Col3
FROM table1
WHERE WeekEnding = '08/26/2012' 
GROUP BY Col1
```

To get

```
Col1   Col2  Col3
 NY     2     2
 FL     1     2
 TX     1     2
 NJ     1     2
 WA     2     2
 DE     1     3
 MA     4     4
 AL     3     3
```

How can I Exclude records where COL2 = COL3, so I get.

```
Col1   Col2  Col3
 FL     1     2
 TX     1     2
 NJ     1     2
 DE     1     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `HAVING` - `having` works after the `group` is done. `Where` works before the `group`.

```
SELECT Col1, count(*) as Col2, Col3
FROM table1
WHERE WeekEnding = '08/26/2012' 
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING Col2 != Col3
```

Note: You are grouping by Col1, but not Col3 - that isn't legal since you are are requesting Col3 in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Col1, count(*) as Col2, Col3
FROM table1
WHERE WeekEnding = '08/26/2012' 
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING (count(*) <> col3)
```